# how to merge 2 tables and get output in Alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables :

**test1**

```
id1 | name1
1   |  a
2   |  s
3   |  d
4   |  t
5   |  z
```

**test2**

```
id2 | name2
1   |  c
2   |  b
3   |  e
4   |  k
5   |  x
```

Need to write a query to generate output in Alphabetical order as

```
a
b
c
d
e
k
s
t
x
z
```

is this thing is possible using just sql queries, no usage of code.

Comment: These are two different questions, that may have already been answered separatly. Have you checked already ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select name 
from (select name1 as name from test1
      union
      select name2 as name from test2
) b order by name
```

Here the internal subquery with return the result of union of two tables and then make the result as temporary table b. Then you can select name from the temporary table ordered by name.

Thanks to @Thorsten Kettner for the update, the above functionality can be done without subquery easily as:

```
select name1 as name from test1
union all
select name2 as name from test2
order by name
```

Edit: Use `union all` to keep the duplicates and it will be bit faster as well.

Comment: That's even more complicated than necessary. You can apply the ORDER BY directly, i.e. 'select ... union select ... order by name`.

Comment: The names of the columns were different that is why I had to do that so that I have common column 'name'.

Comment: You should also mention that one might need to switch to `UNION ALL` to avoid duplicates being removed (if it's known there are no duplicates then it's also faster)

Comment: Do not use `union` unless you want to remove duplicates.  Use `union all`.